# when i am try to redirect to another page in laravel 5.6 then getting error like "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Thank In Advance for view my question

I am working on laravel 5.6 . i am making condition with if statement

like

```
if($value == 5){
   return redirect('Mycon/Home');
}else{
//some thing
}
```

i am also use 
    **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;**
on controller file.
My condition work and also redirect to right url mean 
**http://localhost/sample/test/Mycon/Home**
But After redirect url is right but error show like 
**Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**

I am also add function in route file like
**Route::get('/Home', 'Mycon@Home');**

Comment: What's the root of your Laravel installation? http://localhost/, http://localhost/sample/, http://localhost/sample/test/, or http://localhost/sample/test/Mycon/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you registered the route:

```
Route::get('/Home', 'Mycon@Home');
```

You should redirect like this:

```
return redirect('Home');
```

First param is url, second is the action, if you want to do it by action you should redirect like this:

```
return redirect()->action('Mycon@Home);
```

Comment: Thank for fast reply

Answer (score 1):

Your route is not the same as the redirect route:

```
if($value == 5){
   return redirect('Mycon/Home');
}else{
//some thing
}
```

Route should be something like :

```
Route::get('/Mycon/Home', 'Mycon@Home');
```

**I will suggest the below example:**

**Route**:

```
Route::get('mycon/home', 'MyController@showHome')->name('home');
```

**Redirect**:

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

Have fun :)